# Problem with declaring the source of an image in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is the image's xaml code:

and this is my code for getting the url and showing it:

```
try
{
    MySqlConnection posterConn = new MySqlConnection("***");
    posterConn.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `Poster` WHERE 1", posterConn);
    MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(dr.GetString(1), UriKind.Absolute);
        bitmap.EndInit(); 
        mainPosterImage.Source = bitmap;
    }
}
catch (MySqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Now, When I run the app, nothing happens! I tried to debug, and `bitmap.UriSource`has the exact value of url which is on database.

Why this doesn't work?

I tried to declare the source directly without getting the URL form db & it worked! I think there is a problem inside `while (dr.Read())`. My table has only a row which contains the URL. What can make this problem?

Comment: Does the URI reference a valid image resource on your PC or on the internet? How does it look like?

Comment: @Clemens: when I search the URI on browser, it shows a valid image. source is not on my laptop & it's on internet

Comment: Please post the value of the URL

Comment: @Alander: `https://www.filimo.com/public/public/user_data/movie_cover/cover_19927.jpg`

Comment: @Alander: notice that when I declare the source with the same URL in XAML, it displays the image!

Comment: @Clemens: There is only a record.

Comment: try trimming 

dr.GetString(1).Trim()

Comment: @Alander: tried that before, doesn't solve the problem!

Comment: @Alander: What you mean by RowCount()? MySqlDataReader doesn't support this. but I have checked it again and I am sure that there is only one row in my table.

Comment: Image source can be weird sometimes. I would suggest to try a hardcode value instead of getting it from database. And if it works then try to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: I saw it. That's why I said it just go with hardcode string. Maybe you are not making correct uri/url in your code behind. Try this `var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new System.Uri(@"https://www.filimo.com/public/public/user_data/movie_cover/cover_19927.jpg")); mainPosterImage.Source = bitmap;`

Comment: @Emad: Did you debug your code to find out what value `dr.GetString(1)` returns at runtime? Why don't you specify the column name explicitly in your query instead of * and try `dr.GetString(0)`?

Comment: @fhnaseer: Yes!!! you solved it. Can you please provide what is the exact problem?

Comment: @Emad If `dr.GetString(1)` returned exactly the string that fhnaseer was using, then the only apparent difference between his code and yours is that you specified `UriKind.Absolute`. However, that should just work, because you are dealing with an absolute URI. At the moment, nobody can tell what exactly went wrong. I'd suggest to assign the return value of `dr.GetString(1)` to a string variable and inspect that with a breakpoint in the debugger.

Comment: Maybe your while loop is running more than once. Can you verify it? See if image source is till the same after the loop?